# FontAwesome version 6 React library getting error "process is not defined"

Tags: node.js, reactjs, font-awesome

"I'm receiving the following error when I use the offical FontAwesome (@forawesome) lib.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
  at node_modules/path/path.js (path.js:25:17)
  at __require2 (chunk-LFBQMW2U.js?v=821a7ce7:19:50)
  at node_modules/babel-plugin-macros/dist/index.js (index.js:3:11)
  at __require2 (chunk-LFBQMW2U.js?v=821a7ce7:19:50)
  at node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/import.macro.js (import.macro.js:1:37)
  at __require2 (chunk-LFBQMW2U.js?v=821a7ce7:19:50)
  at import.macro.js:291:1
```

Dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@date-io/dayjs": "^2.16.0",
  "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
  "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
  "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.3.0",
  "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^6.3.0",
  "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.3.0",
  "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.3.0",
  "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
  "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
  "@mui/lab": "^5.0.0-alpha.120",
  "@mui/material": "^5.11.8",
  "@mui/x-data-grid": "^5.17.24",
  "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.20",
  "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.2",
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "axios": "^1.3.2",
  "babel-plugin-macros": "^3.1.0",
  "chart.js": "^4.2.1",
  "classnames": "^2.3.2",
  "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
  "path": "^0.12.7",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
  "react-device-detect": "^2.2.3",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-query": "^3.39.3",
  "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
  "react-responsive": "^9.0.2",
  "react-router": "^6.8.1",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
}
```

Followed the guide to add FontAwesome icons version 6 to react: https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/react/add-icons#alternative-ways-to-add-icons

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you have a `.env` file? If so, please share the contents. It is possible you have an environment variable that does not start with `REACT_APP`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I do not have an `.env` file.